# Can unicode characters be printed in emu8086?

Tags: assembly, unicode, emu8086

I'm creating a "picture" of the aces from a deck of cards by using background colors and symbols  to represent the suits. I've managed to print the "A" in the upper left corner of the card, but I'm stumped on how to print an inverted "A" (∀) for the lower right corner. Is this possible to do in emu8086? I'm a somewhat beginner in assembly and 8086. I've seen an answer to a similar question here regarding printing unicode characters, but I didn't understand what they meant by render or mapping the unicode glyph to character table indexes. Or if this isn't possible, is there a way to make printed characters look inverted in emu8086? As I also need to invert the 4 suit symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPU emulators like emu8086 typically do not only emulate a CPU (a CPU does not have a screen!) but also some hardware components.

I think that 8086 emulators emulate some 1980s or 1990s graphics adapter.

That graphics adapters were able to display a "fixed" set of characters (such as code page 437).

More advanced adapters (such as EGA or VGA cards) also had the ability to exchange the 256 characters of the default set by 256 user-defined characters - but only 256.

The third thing such adapters could do (with exception of text-only adapters) was displaying graphics (such as 320x200, 640x200, 640x350 or 640x480 pixels). In this case you might directly draw an arrow instead of using an "A" for "arrow up".

By the way: Code page 437 had four arrows (for four directions) you could use instead of the "A".

Comment: Just adding the consequences of the good information above. In common text-mode (VGA 80x25 characters) you can NOT display UTF8 texts, as you can define at most only 256 different ones, while 80x25 = 2000, so text using more than 256 different glyphs would fail to render. In graphics mode you can draw any glyph you wish (considering you manage to make it look good on the low-resolution screen, and you manage to cram the font data into memory, which again for full UTF8 is probably impossible, as you have only about 400-500kiB of memory). Either way you have to put lot of own code to do that.

Comment: @OP: As you are interested only into to draw deck of card, and not any UTF8 text, either explore the old VGA default font to see which symbols are already available, it may turn out to be enough, or use the custom font data to create few more additional glyphs, then output them as part of text. Going full into graphic mode is another option, using then images for cards, but I would start with text-mode and VGA charset, there are common card symbols, only the upside-down letters are not available. (by UTF8 above I mean "unicode" characters. Made me giggle, unicode didn't exist when PC started)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm restricted to the VGA 80x25 characters, so I guess I'll just have to be creative and use the already available symbols. Thank you to the two of you.